# draw rotation axis in triangular prism

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, draw

How can I draw a vertical and horizontal rotation axis for a triangular prism? One approach looks as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- (2,-2) -- (3.5,0);
 \draw (0,4) -- (2,2) -- (3.5,4);
 \draw (0,0) -- (0,4);
 \draw (2,-2) -- (2,2);
 \draw (3.5,0) -- (3.5,4);
 \draw (0,4) -- (3.5,4);
 \draw[dashed,thick] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
 % Achse 1
 \draw (5.5/3, 10/3) circle (0.1);
 \draw (5.5/3, 10/3 -4) circle (0.1);
 \draw[color=gray,thick] (5.5/3, 5) -- (5.5/3, -3);
 % Achse 2
 \draw (1,1) circle (0.1);
 \draw (3.5,2) circle (0.1);
  \draw[color=gray,thick] (-1,1-2/2.5) -- (4.5,2 + 1/2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there an alternative approach? Especially I want to rotate clockwise. How can I make this clear in the drawing?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[lbl/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt},>={Latex[bend]}]
 \draw[dashed,thick]  (0,2.5) coordinate(T) (-1,0) coordinate(BL) -- (0,0.5) coordinate(B)
  edge (T) -- (1,0) coordinate(BR);
 \draw[<-] ($(T)!0.5!(BL)$) to[out=90,in=-45] ++ (-0.5,1) node[lbl,above left]{5};
 \draw[<-] ($(T)!0.5!(BR)$) to[out=90,in=-135] ++ (0.5,1) node[lbl,above right]{4};
 \draw[<-] (0.1,0.3) to[bend left=20] ++ (0,-0.5) node[lbl,below]{2};
 \draw[thick,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7] (BL)   rectangle (1,2) coordinate(TR) 
 -- (0,2.5)  -- (-1,2) coordinate(TL);
 \path (-0.2,1)  node[lbl]{1};
 \draw[<-] ($(T)+(-0.1,-0.3)$) to[bend left=20] ++ (0,0.5) node[lbl,above]{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

@Schrödinger's cat: After compiling your code I get the following result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective,arrows.meta,bending,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-10}{15},line cap=round,line join=round,
    declare function={rr=0.2;a=2;h=4;}]
 \draw[densely dashed] (-a,0,0) -- (a,0,0) 
    plot[variable=\t,domain=-90:-270,smooth] 
        ({a+rr*cos(\t)},{0},{h/2+rr*sin(\t)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=00:360,smooth cycle] 
        ({rr*cos(\t)},{-a/2+rr*sin(\t)},{0});
 % horizontal axis
 \draw[very thick] ({a},{0},{h/2}) --  ({-a/2},{-a*sqrt(3)/2},{h/2});
 % verical axis
 \draw[very thick] ({0},{-a/2},{-h/4}) --  ({0},{-a/2},{h});
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \path (-a/3,-a/3) node[circle,draw,transform shape,yscale=-1]{4};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[thick,{Stealth[bend]}-] (0,-a/2)+(30:rr) arc[start angle=30,end angle=330,radius=rr];
 \end{scope}

 % left face
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.8,even odd rule] 
  (-a,0,0) -- (-a,0,h) -- (0,{-a*sqrt(3)},h) -- (0,{-a*sqrt(3)},0) 
  -- cycle
  plot[variable=\t,domain=00:360,smooth cycle] 
        ({-a/2+rr*cos(\t)/2},{-sqrt(3)*rr*cos(\t)/2-a*sqrt(3)/2},{h/2+rr*sin(\t)});
 % right face
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.8] (a,0,0) -- (a,0,h/2-rr) --
    plot[variable=\t,domain=-90:-270,smooth] 
        ({a+rr*cos(\t)/2},{sqrt(3)*rr*cos(\t)/2},{h/2+rr*sin(\t)})
  -- (a,0,h) -- (0,{-a*sqrt(3)},h) -- (0,{-a*sqrt(3)},0) -- cycle;
 % top face
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.8,even odd rule]
  (-a,0,h) -- (0,{-a*sqrt(3)},h) -- (a,0,h) -- cycle
  plot[variable=\t,domain=00:360,smooth cycle] 
        ({rr*cos(\t)},{-a/2+rr*sin(\t)},{h}); 
 \draw[very thick] ({-a/2},{-a*sqrt(3)/2},{h/2}) --  
 ({-a/2-3*a/4},{-3*a*sqrt(3)/4},{h/2})
 ({a},{0},{h/2}) -- ({a+3*a/4},{a*sqrt(3)/4},{h/2});
 \draw[very thick] ({0},{-a/2},{h}) --  ({0},{-a/2},{5*h/4}) ;
 \path  (-a/2,{-a*sqrt(3)/2},3*h/4) coordinate (1)
 (a/2,{-a*sqrt(3)/2},3*h/4) coordinate (2);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=5*h/4]
  \path (0,-2.5*a) node[circle,draw,transform shape,yscale=-1]{3};;
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[thick,{Stealth[bend]}-] (0,-a/2)+(30:rr) arc[start angle=30,end angle=330,radius=rr];
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[3d view={-40}{15},canvas is yz plane at x=2.1*a]
  \path (1) node[circle,draw,transform shape,xscale=-1]{1};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[thick,-{Stealth[bend]}] (0,h/2-1.5*rr)+(30:rr) arc[start angle=30,end angle=330,radius=rr];
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[3d view={-160}{15},canvas is yz plane at x=2.1*a]
  \path (2) node[circle,draw,transform shape,xscale=-1]{2};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are awesome! Thank you very much! Can you include the direction of the rotation and the labeling? The labeling should look as follows (see above!)

Comment: How can I make the upper circle on the vertical axis to be clockwise?

Comment: @wayne You can revert an arrow by changing `-{Stealth[bend]}` to `{Stealth[bend]}-`.

Comment: If I compile your code I get the following result (see above). Why is this so?

Comment: @wayne I have no idea. Maybe you have not updated your TeX installation in a long time?

Comment: I have fix the problem. It was the old version of TeX. Thanks for the help!